# Get children of a OneToMany relationship

Tags: scala, quill.io

With Ebean, you can access a OneToMany relationship with an accessor.

What is the best way to do this in Quill ?

Is there a way to do it with the "for-comprehension" syntax ?
Should that be handled in classic scala `groupBy`, afterwards ?

Here is a scastie that works with `SqlMirrorContext` :
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/lEsCs2MqTUutjPnhnPuIzA

I wrote exactly that in my project with `PostgresqlJdbcContext`, and it fails :

```
column "x4.author_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

For those who are at the same point, I ended up by `groupBy` with pure scala (outside the query), which is still acceptable.